# Проблема с организацией вывода элементов массива

Tags: массивы, pascal, pascalabc.net

Мне нужно заполнить вектор ГПСЧ. Я это сделал. Далее нужно Вывести элементы массива в таком порядке:

```
a1,a10,a2,a11...a9,a18
```

Код, который я написал, находит только первые два элемента в том порядке, который мне нужен. Т.е., a1,a10 Это происходит в силу того, что шаг (i) становиться > N.
Очень нужна помощь, что можно сделать с этой проблемой.

Код:

```
const Sz = 100; // Размер массива

var 
  a: array [1..Sz] of real;
  N: integer; // Количество элементов в массиве
  i: integer;

begin
  N := 18;
  for i:=1 to N do
    a[i] := Random(100) * 0.6;

  write('Сгенерированные элементы массива > ');
  for i:=1 to N do
    begin
    if i <> N then
      write(i, ') ', a[i],'; ');
    if i = N then
      writeln(i, ') ', a[i],'. ');
    end;
    writeln();

    write('Искомые элементы > ');
    i := 1;
    while N >= i do
      begin
      if i <> N then
      write(i, ') ', a[i],'; ');
      if i = N then {проверка на последний элемент, для точки}
      writeln(i, ') ', a[i],'. ');
      i+=9;
    end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i := 1;
while N >= (i + 9) do
begin
  write(a[i], a[i + 9]);
  Inc(i);
end;
```

Comment: Гениально! Обязательно отмечу Ваш ответ

Comment: @РоманРатушный Пока мы ждем 15 минут со времени создания вопроса, чтобы не скучать, Вы можете нажать слева стрелочку (треугольник) "вверх".